# The orange count indicator broken on multiline items in Saved Searches & Alerts

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, design

After saving a job search, it appears in the Saved Searches & Alerts box on the right, and includes an orange marker with the number of jobs.

If, however the search had multiple criteria, the item in the list becomes long and results in it spanning multiple lines, then the orange indicator breaks, as seen in a sample screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: again a flex-shrink issue ...need to add flex-shrink:0 to that icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

There nothing a `white-space: nowrap` can't take care of.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it. I can confirm that it renders correctly now.